# Got weird partial binomial sum result

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution

While working on probabalistic question and binomial distribution got the following result:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}\sum_{l=0}^{k}\binom{n+1}l = 2^{2n}$$

or in other words sum of binomial coefficients multiplied by the partial sum of binomial sequence of $n+1$ order.

Does it have some nice explanation?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Like solving the inner sum and checking the binomial theorem?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I checked on partial binomial sums and it doesn't seem to be something simple and nice.

Answer (score 5):

The sum is
$$
\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\sum_{l=0}^k\left[\binom{n}{l-1}+\binom{n}{l}\right]\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\left[\binom{n}k+2\sum_{l=0}^{k-1}\binom nl\right]\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^2+2\sum_{j,k\colon 0\le l<k\le n}
\binom nl\binom nk.
\end{align}$$
The double sum here is the sum of $\binom nl\binom nk$ over all
$k$, $l\in\{0,\ldots,n\}$ with $k\ne l$. Thus
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{l=0}^n\binom nl\binom nk=(1+1)^n(1+1)^n.$$